# Store multiple account credentials in iOS keychain

Tags: ios, keychain

I am currently building an iOS app that allows the user to have multiple accounts logged in at the same time.  I want to use keychain to hold the users account credentials, which is easy if you are dealing with one account.

I can't seem to find a good example of dealing with multiple accounts in keychain. Is it just a case of creating a new instance of KeychainItemWrapper with a different identifier every time a new account is added?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did u get a solution to store multiple credentials in keychain

Answer (score 0):

I think you are correct, it will need a new KeychainItemWrapper. I have a similar case but decided to use [SSKeychain](https://github.com/soffes/sskeychain) and add another account.